# XAMPP installation and control panel issue

Tags: xampp

**XAMPP INSTALLATION PROBLEM**
After installation, **XAMPP** is showing in the startup panel in **Windows 10**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall xampp and reinstall latest version from official site 
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html